# How to link to another .html.erb file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with my Rails project and I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LeaguesController#show Couldn't find
>   League with 'id'=about

This is my `link_to`:

`<%= link_to 'About', about_path %>`

My controller:

```
class LeaguesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_league, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /leagues
  # GET /leagues.json
  def index
    @leagues = League.all
  end

  def about
  end

  # GET /leagues/1
  # GET /leagues/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /leagues/new
  def new
    @league = League.new
  end
end
```

And my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :leagues
    get '/leagues/about' => 'leagues#about', as: => :about
end
```

Please help me, I want to link my `index.html.erb` to `my about.html.erb`.

Comment: The problem is in your `show` method, you're passing an `id` in the needed params, as you have `resources :leagues` it adds the entry for `/leagues/:id`, so you need an id but you're passing `about`, what's that `link_to`?. What do you want, to respond with `index.html.erb` being at 'leagues/about', create a `link_to` pointing to `about_path`, what?

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Type rake routes in your terminal and show the results.

Comment: I want to link index.html.erb to about.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

In the rails [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) This exact situation is covered:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first

Instead of `:photos` you have `:leagues` and instead of `/poll` you have `/about`. So, just need to swap those 2 lines in your routing file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get '/leagues/about' => 'leagues#about', as: :about
    resources :leagues
end
```

For this situation, you could also do

```
resources :leagues do
  get 'about', on: :collection
end
```

and end up with

```
Prefix        Verb    URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
about_leagues GET    /leagues/about(.:format)    leagues#about
```

and end up with `about_leagues_path` as the helper (which might be better than `about_path`, about what? What if you have an `/teams/about` as well, later on, is `about_path` about teams or leagues?)

Comment: where should I put my def about? after the index?

Comment: Inside the controller, the method order doesn't make any difference (the controller you posted in the question looks fine). Did you restart your server after changing the routing order?

Comment: Interesting, just created a new rails app then did a `rails g scaffold League` and added your `about` route beneath the `resources :leagues` route in config/routes.rb. Then I added your `link_to` line in the 'leagues/index.html.erb' and added an `about` method to the controller and a corresponding view file. Clicking the link triggered your error. Stopped the server and moved the `about` route above the `resources :leagues` and tried it again and everything worked fine. Which rails are you seeing this in?

Comment: is the index.html.erb and about.html.erb under the views/leagues folder?

Comment: yeah `app/views/leagues/index.html.erb` and `app/views/leagues/about.html.erb`

Comment: does the def about has content or none?

Comment: the `about` method is empty for me

Comment: NameError in Leagues#about
undefined local variable or method `leagues_about_path' for #<#<Class:0x4484bb0>:0x9943b60>
 <li><%= link_to 'Create League', new_league_path %></li>
                <ul style="float: right; list-style: none;">
                    <li><%= link_to 'About', leagues_about_path %></li>
                </ul>
   </ul>
  <nav>

Comment: <%= link_to 'About', about_path %> is this your link?
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get '/leagues/about' => 'leagues#about', as: :about
 resources :leagues
end
and your routes.rb?

Comment: yeah, just used `about_path`; didn't do the nesting bit. That was just an alternative way to solve your problem that would end up with `about_leagues_path` instead of `about_path`....if you didn't do the nesting (it doesn't look like you did), it'll still be `about_path`

Comment: Dude!!!! What the f. Thank you so muchhhhhh! It worked. Appreciated it so much. The error is that in my about.html.erb. I got the same link that doesn't match with the one in the index. <%= link_to 'About', leagues_about_path %> my bad. :D

Comment: I will put you in the credit page of this project. haha

Answer (score 1):

`resources :leagues` generates the routes

```
          leagues GET    /leagues(.:format)                        leagues#index
                  POST   /leagues(.:format)                        leagues#create
       new_league GET    /leagues/new(.:format)                    leagues#new
      edit_league GET    /leagues/:id/edit(.:format)               leagues#edit
           league GET    /leagues/:id(.:format)                    leagues#show
                  PATCH  /leagues/:id(.:format)                    leagues#update
                  PUT    /leagues/:id(.:format)                    leagues#update
                  DELETE /leagues/:id(.:format)                    leagues#destroy
```

Then, the custom route you want to add has the same URL blueprint as that of route delegated for `leagues#show` action (i.e `/leagues/:id`
), which the rails router assumes `:id` to be 'about'. You can use `match` to solve this:

```
match '/leagues/about' => 'leagues#about', as: :about, via: :get
```

Comment: I thought `match ..., via: :get` and `get ...` were the same thing, just `match` allowed you to match against multiple verbs in one line

Comment: yes .. `match` can also be used to tap keywords in a URL pattern .. in this case 'about' keyword is matched to `/leaves/about` route instead of `/leaves/:id`